# Скрыть элемент с одинаковой ссылкой страницы сайта

Tags: javascript, css

Народ всем привет в Joomla 3 есть модуль последние новости, но он например при открытии страницы может показывать новость которая уже открыта и от этого хотелось бы избавится абсолютно любым путем. Например есть ли скрипт который будет скрывать блок если url страницы совпадает с блоком? Или что-то в этом роде подскажите где копать, пожалуйста.

```js
<?php
/**
 * @package MJ Simple News
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 * @copyright (c) 2013 MicroJoom. All Rights Reserved.
 * @author MicroJoom http://www.microjoom.com
 * 
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if(!empty($list)){
    // ID for html module
    $tag_id = 'mj_simple_news_'.time().rand();
    $jquery_lazyload = (int)$params->get('jquery_lazyload');
    // Include  Css
    JHtml::stylesheet('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/css/styles.css');
    if($jquery_lazyload){
        global $mjquery;
        if( !isset($mjquery) && (int)$params->get('local_jquery', 0) ){
            JHtml::script('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js');
            JHtml::script('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/js/jquery-noconflict.js');
            $mjquery = '2.0.3';
        }
        JHtml::script('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/js/jquery.lazyload.js');
    }
    // Get params configuration
    $preset_class = array();
    $preset_class[] =  'cols-lg-' . $params->get('col_lg', 6);
    $preset_class[] =  'cols-md-' . $params->get('col_md', 4);
    $preset_class[] =  'cols-sm-' . $params->get('col_sm', 2);
    $preset_class[] =  'cols-xs-' . $params->get('col_xs', 1);
    $preset_class   = implode(' ', $preset_class);
    $readmore_display       = (int)$params->get('item_readmore_display');
?>  
    <!--Begin mj-simple-news-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><div class="mj-simple-news msie lt-ie9" id="<?php echo $tag_id; ?>"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]><div class="mj-simple-news msie" id="<?php echo $tag_id; ?>"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><div class="mj-simple-news" id="<?php echo $tag_id; ?>"><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--Begin sn-items-->
        <div class="sn-items cf <?php echo $preset_class;  ?>">
            <?php  $j= 0; 
            foreach($list as $item){  $j++;  ?>
            <!--Begin sn-item-->
            <div class="sn-item ">
                <!--Begin sn-item-inner-->
                <div class="sn-item-inner">
                    <!--Begin sn-image-->
                    <?php
                    $imgattr = '';
                    $imgsrc = $item->image_src;
                    if($jquery_lazyload) {
                        $imgattr = ' data-original="'.JURI::base().$item->image_src.'"';
                        $imgsrc  = JURI::base().'modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/img/white.gif';
                    }
                    if($imgsrc) { ?>
                    <div class="sn-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" <?php echo $item->link_target; ?>>
                            <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc  ?>" <?php echo $imgattr.' '.$item->image_attr ?> />
                        </a>
                        <?php if($item->_created != '' || $item->_hits != '') { ?>
                        <div class="sn-created-hits">
                            <?php if($item->_created != ''){ ?>
                            <span class="sn-created">
                                <?php echo  JText::_('PUBLISHED_LABEL').JHTML::_('date', $item->_created,JText::_('m-d-Y')); ?>
                            </span>
                            <?php }
                            if($item->_hits != ''){ ?>
                            <span class="sn-hits">
                                <?php echo JText::_('HITS_LABEL').$item->_hits; ?>
                            </span> 
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <!--End sn-image-->
                    <?php
                    $show_infor = $item->sub_title != '' ||  $item->_description != '' || $item->tags != '' || $readmore_display;
                    if($show_infor) {   ?>
                    <!--Begin sn-infor-->
                    <div class="sn-infor">
                        <?php if($item->sub_title != '') {?>
                        <div class="sn-title">
                            <a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" <?php echo $item->link_target; ?>>
                                <?php echo $item->sub_title; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php }
                        if($item->_description != '') {?>
                        <div class="sn-description">
                            <?php echo $item->_description; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php }
                        if($item->tags != ''){?>
                        <div class="sn-tags">
                            <?php echo $item->tags; ?>
                        </div>  
                        <?php }
                        if($readmore_display){?>
                        <div class="sn-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>"  <?php echo $item->link_target; ?>>
                                <?php echo JText::_('READ_MORE_TEXT'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                    <!--End sn-infor-->
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--End sn-item-inner-->
            </div>
            <!--End sn-item-->
             <?php
            $clear = 'clr1';
            if ($j % 2 == 0) $clear .= ' clr2';
            if ($j % 3 == 0) $clear .= ' clr3';
            if ($j % 4 == 0) $clear .= ' clr4';
            if ($j % 5 == 0) $clear .= ' clr5';
            if ($j % 6 == 0) $clear .= ' clr6';
            ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $clear; ?>"></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!--End sn-items-->
    </div>
    <!--End mj-simple-news-->
    <?php
    if($jquery_lazyload){?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 
         jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
            ;(function(element){
                var $element = $(element);
                    $('img',$element).lazyload({
                        effect: 'fadeIn',
                        effect_speed:1000,
                        load: function(){
                            $(this).removeAttr("data-original");
                        }
                    });
            })('#<?php echo $tag_id; ?>'); 
        }); 
    //]]>   
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
<?php 
}else{
    //  Do not display this message for guest.
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    if( $user->id ){
        echo JText::_('WARNING_LABEL'); 
    }
}?>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').style.display = "none";` - что-то около того. Надо смотреть, что именно у вас записано в href и обработать строку соответствующим образом.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME От меня что требуется я могу дать ссылку на сайт или код?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME я добавил код, хотя бы пример на 1 ссылке покажите я дальше сам.

Comment: я не знаком с cms и не знаю как реализованы эти новостные блоки, могу только такой костыль предоставить  `const thisUrl = window.location.href , 
anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let anchor of anchors) {
  if( thisUrl == anchor.href){
    anchor.style.display = "none";
  }
}`